# Finding transpose of each element of list separately in python

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I have a List of N items, each of d dimensions (so essentially a N x d list). For each of the items, I want to find the product of item transposed with itself, So, x.xT for each of the N items. This will give me a N x d x d array. How can I do it efficiently in numpy. At this moment, I am looping through each of the items and finding the transpose separately.

```
for i in range(len(mu[0])):
    current_mu = mu[i] # list of d elements
    distances = []
    for index in range(len(samples)):
        distance = np.asarray(current_mu - samples[index])[:, None] # list of d elements
        distances.append(distance * distance.T) # each becomes d x d
```

Can I remove the second nested loop or is it required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

N,d = 10,5

mu = np.random.rand(N,d)
r = np.einsum('ni,nj->nij', mu, mu)

r.shape
(10,5,5)
```

Comparing to a for-loop implementation:

```py
def for_loop(a):
    N,d = a.shape
    r = np.zeros((N,d,d))
    for i in range(N):
        r[i] = a[i][:,None] @ a[i][None,:]

# N>d case
N,d = 1000,500
mu = np.random.rand(N,d)

%timeit np.einsum('ni,nj->nij', mu, mu)
1.29 s ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit for_loop(mu)
2.36 s ± 45.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# N<d case
N,d = 100,1000
mu = np.random.rand(N,d)

%timeit np.einsum('ni,nj->nij', mu, mu)
521 ms ± 9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit for_loop(mu)
976 ms ± 18.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In both cases resulting in almost 2x performances.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to work that with the transpose of the row? So np.einsum('ni,nj->nij', mu, mu), have mu and mu.T instead?

Comment: I found it -> np.einsum('nij,nji->nij', mu, mu). Can you update the answer with this, as the question was specifically meant for transposition of the vectors? I will mark this answer accepted as this reduced my time from 1s to 1ms. (I had d = 3). Thanks again :)

Comment: @lokiysh Feel free to edit the answer as you intended, or I will do it later as I am from my phone now.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by @FBruzzesi works perfectly, but if anyone prefers a solution without using einsum (and completeness in general):

```
n,d=1000,500
x=np.random.randn(n,d,1)
x_einsum=x.reshape(n,d)

%timeit x * x.transpose((0,2,1))
744 ms ± 48.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.einsum('ni,nj->nij', x_einsum, x_einsum)
777 ms ± 18.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```